# Mysql parent child in same table

Tags: sql, join

I have following table layout (all in one table SQL):

```
user_id, user_id_parent, fname, lname, shopname
```

I want to be able to print out fname and lastname and show what shop name the user is related to via (user_id_parent(is refering to user_id, you could say that user_id is a kind of shopname id) ). If it is a normal useracount in this case, the shopname is empty.

I would guess I should use som kind of Join, but i don't know how to use it when it's in the same table...

Result something like:

```
John Doe, Relating to: Shop #1
```

Comment: You really should have split that into two different tables.. but yes, you can do it (as your answer demonstrates).

Answer (score 0):

I did this working SQL and guess what, Tada! :-)
Posting this, so it may help other guys trying to do the same thing.

```
SELECT e.`user_type` AS usertype, e.`fname` AS employee, m.`shopname` AS associated_to
FROM rw_users e
INNER JOIN rw_users m ON e.`user_id_parent` = m.`user_id`
```

Comment: But right now it seems that i can't use a WHERE `usertype`=5. Why? I do not really under stand it :/

Comment: It's becaus i can't use aliases in where, but what do i do then? :P

Comment: Just did, WHERE e.`usertype`=number